# Changing the column padding of Three Columns with Header Layout

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, css

I would like to adjust the amount of padding between each of the three different columns in my SharePoint Page. Is there a CSS script that would allow me to do this?

[image]

Comment: Could you select the element you want increased using Browser tools? F12. What is the current padding?

Comment: Tried to use that but couldn't find anything that had padding around 30px..